# How to pass text box value as argument in jquery function on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textbox, parameter-passing

**I want to get a value of text box on click as parameter**

```
<input type="text" id="remark_mention" />
```

// link is here for click

```
<a class="remark  "href="javascript:void(0);"style="text-decoration:none;color:#d90000;" id="st_mention<?php echo strip_tags($row["pid"]); ?>" onClick="mention_or_remmove_remarks('<?php echo strip_tags($row["pid"]); ?>','st_mention');"> Mention</a>
```

**My jquery function is follow**

```
function mention_or_remmove_remarks(mention_id, action){
    var dataString = "mention_id=" + mention_id + "&action=mention_or_remmove_remarks";//ajax code here for post mention_update.php 
}
```

**How I get a value of textbox in link Onclick event**

Comment: no close I am fresher and a question is clear you should respect the beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by.

Use form and get it:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="remark_mention" name="remark_mention_ID"/>
<input type="button" onclick="foo(this.form.remark_mention_ID.value)"/>
</form>
```

OR :

```
<input type="text" id="remark_mention" />
```

and in your js file :

```
var value = $('#remark_mention').val(); // value variable has your latest value
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<input type="text" id="remark_mention" />
<a class="remark "href="javascript:void(0);"> Mention</a>
```

Js

```
$('.remark').on('click', function(){
    var text_val = $('#remark_mention').val();
    console.log(text_val);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/894708/)